# Is it possible to remove "Inspect Element"?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-app

Is it possible to remove or disable "Inspect Element" context menu in Chrome App via Javascript?

I have searched through several forums but there are no definite answer.

Comment: You mean the right click menu?

Comment: @David: yes, david and I just found out the solution by using oncontextmenu="return false".

Comment: Jep very true! good job

Comment: Why do you want to disable the context menu? This can be turned off in browsers (preventing scripts to disable it). Then there are (shortcut) keys (F12 for win/linux) to do element inspection.

Comment: because I am creating a chrome app and client doesn't want users to be able to see the source codes.

Comment: You can't!!!  Ctrl+Mayus+I Can open the Devtools of Chrome always!!!

Comment: Yeah, by doing a web app users will *always* be able to see the source code. You should go for a native desktop app instead

Comment: Well, when you say they don't want them to be able to see source code, do you mean the code that generates the pages?  Because to show them anything, you have to send them HTML.  You have the option of doing minimal javascript, so everything is generated on the server, which will be a black box to them (they can't see what happens there), but to give them a web page, you MUST send them HTML (unless you want to use a plugin like Flash or a Java Applet, but even those can be reverse engineered, decompiled, etc).

Answer (score 24, accepted):

It is possible to prevent the user from opening the context menu by right clicking like this (javascript):

```
document.addEventListener('contextmenu', function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
});
```

By listening to the `contextmenu` event and preventing the default behavior which is "showing the menu", the menu won't be shown.
But the user will still be able to inspect code through the console (by pressing F12 in Chrome for example).

Comment: But this will prevent right click only. Is there a way to prevent keyboard shortcuts?

Comment: Please don't do this. This is super harmful for web accessibility. Even if it's what the question asked for, I'm afraid folks will put this snippet into production.

Answer (score 81):

I have one requirement for one page. On that page, I want to block the user from performing the below actions,

- Right Click
- F12
- Ctrl + Shift + I
- Ctrl + Shift + J
- Ctrl + Shift + C
- Ctrl + U

For this, I googled and finally got the below link,

http://andrewstutorials.blogspot.in/2014/03/disable-ways-to-open-inspect-element-in.html

I tested it with Chrome & Firefox. It's working for my requirement.

**Right Click**

```
 <body oncontextmenu="return false">
```

**Keys**

```js
document.onkeydown = (e) => {
    if (e.key == 123) {
        e.preventDefault();
    }
    if (e.ctrlKey && e.shiftKey && e.key == 'I') {
        e.preventDefault();
    }
    if (e.ctrlKey && e.shiftKey && e.key == 'C') {
        e.preventDefault();
    }
    if (e.ctrlKey && e.shiftKey && e.key == 'J') {
        e.preventDefault();
    }
    if (e.ctrlKey && e.key == 'U') {
        e.preventDefault();
    }
};
```

Comment: Above method is disable for mouse and keyboard but what if i go to Developer tools and inspect from there.

Comment: There is still one more way - the user can click the "..." menu in the upper-right corner, select "More Tools", and click "Developer tools".

Answer (score 15):

**You can't.**

Everything on a web page is rendered by the browser, and they want web sites to properly work on them or their users would despise them.
As a result, browsers want to expose the lower level ticks of everything to the web developers with tools like code inspectors.

You could try to prevent the user from entering the menu with a key event. Something like this:

```
// Disable inspect element
$(document).bind("contextmenu",function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
});
$(document).keydown(function(e){
  if(e.which === 123){
    return false;
}
});
```

But if a user want to see the code, he will do it in another way. He will just need a little longer.

**Short**: If you do not want people to get something in their browser, you **shouldn't send it to their browser** in the first place.

Answer (score 7):

It is *kinda* possible.

1. Firstly, use [ramakrishna's](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44601125/4781067) solution to block the devtools shortcut keys.
2. Add [devtools-detect](https://github.com/sindresorhus/devtools-detect) to your website. Here is a quick link for the [devtools.js](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/sindresorhus/devtools-detect/master/index.js) file from his github.
3. Then, finally, add the following:

```
if (devtools.isOpen) {


    setInterval(() => {

        var $all = document.querySelectorAll("*");

        for (var each of $all) {
            each.classList.add(`asdjaljsdliasud8ausdijaisdluasdjasildahjdsk${Math.random()}`);
        }
        

    }, 5);
}
```

or maybe this:

```
if (devtools.isOpen) {
while (true) {
    console.log("access denied")
}
}
```

It will basically overload the DOM and make it impossible to interact with it via the devtools.

Additionally, this is a mere example; you can use much more elaborate ways to overload the DOM instead of just adding classes.

I don't think it will work flawlessly but it should be enough to offer at least some extra minor layer of "security".

Comment: That tool merely checks to see when the effective browser window size differs from the possible maximum window size. It won't work at all when developer tools preferences open the tools in a new window.

Answer (score 5):

```js
  

 "put this script before ending your body tag"

 <script> 
      document.addEventListener('contextmenu', event=> event.preventDefault()); 
      document.onkeydown = function(e) { 
      if(event.keyCode == 123) { 
      return false; 
      } 
      if(e.ctrlKey && e.shiftKey && e.keyCode == 'I'.charCodeAt(0)){ 
      return false; 
      } 
      if(e.ctrlKey && e.shiftKey && e.keyCode == 'J'.charCodeAt(0)){ 
      return false; 
      } 
      if(e.ctrlKey && e.keyCode == 'U'.charCodeAt(0)){ 
      return false; 
      } 
      } 
      </script>
```

Answer (score 3):

While not an answer, Chrome certainly has a way to do this, I appear to be in an A/B test as my work account can't inspect in Gmail, meanwhile my personal account can.

I've searched for `<meta>` tags or HTTP headers which might be controlling this, but nothing stands out

[image: Gmail blocking Inspect option]

Comment: This is the organization (your admin) controlling the account, not the website. Websites can't control whether or not you can inspect elements.

Comment: but still, it is possible!

Answer (score 3):

Yes, there is, some of the above scripts successfully disable one but can't close the other so below's the summary of the above.

```
document.addEventListener('contextmenu',(e)=>{
    e.preventDefault();
  }
  );
  document.onkeydown = function(e) {
  if(event.keyCode == 123) {
     return false;
  }
  if(e.ctrlKey && e.shiftKey && e.keyCode == 'I'.charCodeAt(0)) {
     return false;
  }
  if(e.ctrlKey && e.shiftKey && e.keyCode == 'C'.charCodeAt(0)) {
     return false;
  }
  if(e.ctrlKey && e.shiftKey && e.keyCode == 'J'.charCodeAt(0)) {
     return false;
  }
  if(e.ctrlKey && e.keyCode == 'U'.charCodeAt(0)) {
     return false;
  }
}
```

Use this and you are all secure, now nobody can steal ur code or use js to crack open ur database!

Comment: Except now things like Burp Suite are now a thing. Edit: I know that it existed before this answer was posted

Answer (score 2):

Nope. Closest you can do is capture right clicks, and make them not open the context menu, but the savvy user will know the keyboard combos or menu options to access it anyway, defeating the point.  That's a feature of the browser, so nothing you do in your page is going to defeat it (short of installing malware on their computer).

Comment: Overwrite keyboard keystrokes :D

Comment: Besides, you can always open `chrome://inspect`.

Answer (score 2):

Add this to the html tag of your page

```
<html oncontextmenu="return false">
```

Answer (score 2):

```
document.addEventListener('keydown', function() {
    if (event.keyCode == 123) {
      alert("You Can not Do This!");
      return false;
    } else if (event.ctrlKey && event.shiftKey && event.keyCode == 73) {
      alert("You Can not Do This!");
      return false;
    } else if (event.ctrlKey && event.keyCode == 85) {
      alert("You Can not Do This!");
      return false;
    }
  }, false);
  
  if (document.addEventListener) {
    document.addEventListener('contextmenu', function(e) {
      alert("You Can not Do This!");
      e.preventDefault();
    }, false);
  } else {
    document.attachEvent('oncontextmenu', function() {
      alert("You Can not Do This!");
      window.event.returnValue = false;
    });
  }
```

No F12 No Rightclick

Hi
I use this codes.
Have fun♥

Answer (score 1):

well yes its possible to stop inspecting the website into the browser.
as you know that there are three ways to inspect a website into the browser

1. using keyboard shortcuts
2. using right click
3. using developer menu of the browser

i have solution for the 1 and the 2 ways here is the JavaScript code
but user user 3rd way is very rare cases

```
// take body to change the content
const body = document.getElementsByTagName('body');
// stop keyboard shortcuts
window.addEventListener("keydown", (event) => {
  if(event.ctrlKey && (event.key === "S" || event.key === "s")) {
     event.preventDefault();
     body[0].innerHTML = "sorry, you can't do this "
  }

  if(event.ctrlKey && (event.key === "C")) {
     event.preventDefault();
     body[0].innerHTML = "sorry, you can't do this "
  }
  if(event.ctrlKey && (event.key === "E" || event.key === "e")) {
     event.preventDefault();
     body[0].innerHTML = "sorry, you can't do this "
  }
  if(event.ctrlKey && (event.key === "I" || event.key === "i")) {
     event.preventDefault();
     body[0].innerHTML = "sorry, you can't do this ";
  }
  if(event.ctrlKey && (event.key === "K" || event.key === "k")) {
     event.preventDefault();
     body[0].innerHTML = "sorry, you can't do this ";
  }
  if(event.ctrlKey && (event.key === "U" || event.key === "u")) {
     event.preventDefault();
     body[0].innerHTML = "sorry, you can't do this ";
  }
});
// stop right click
document.addEventListener('contextmenu', function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<script language="javascript">
document.onmousedown=disableclick;
status="Right Click Disabled";
function disableclick(event)
{
  if(event.button==2)
   {
     alert(status);
     return false;    
   }
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

In case it helps anyone, Inspect Element can be disabled for an individual element by adding the style `pointer-events: none;` to it.

This is very useful if you have any elements that are purely for the purpose of aligning child elements that necessarily overlap a large area of more useful elements; it lets you prevent the aligner elements from responding to the Inspect Element command.

Comment: They can always open the devtools and navigate to the element that has the inspect menu "disabled".

Comment: @Reality This tip is not about stopping visitors from inspecting elements (good luck with that), but about helping you, the developer, make Inspect Element better at picking out the element you're interested in (the one you can see) rather than some large invisible element that might overlap it.

Comment: oh, yes. That really *would* help. How many times have I tried to select an element but get the backdrop instead lol.

Answer (score 0):

You can not block it, but you can stop some keys:

Add this to your script:

```
<script>
 
 document.addEventListener('contextmenu', function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
 });
 document.addEventListener('keydown', function(e) {
 if (event.keyCode == 123) {
  return false;
 }
 if (e.ctrlKey && e.shiftKey) {
  return false;
 }
 if (event.ctrlKey && event.keyCode == 85) {
  return false;
 }
});
/* other script code */
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Above Answer Is Perfect but has some issue when pression ctrl+shift+I. in previous answer it still opens inspect. By Adding event.preventdefault() solve this problem

```js
document.addEventListener('keydown', function() {
    if (event.keyCode == 123) {
      alert("You Can not Do This!");
      return false;
    } else if (event.ctrlKey && event.shiftKey && event.keyCode == 73) {
      alert("You Can not Do This!");
       event.preventDefault();
      return false;
    } else if (event.ctrlKey && event.keyCode == 85) {
      alert("You Can not Do This!");
      return false;
    }
  }, false);
  
  if (document.addEventListener) {
    document.addEventListener('contextmenu', function(e) {
      alert("You Can not Do This!");
      e.preventDefault();
    }, false);
  } else {
    document.attachEvent('oncontextmenu', function() {
      alert("You Can not Do This!");
      window.event.returnValue = false;
    });
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
document.onkeydown = function(e) {
if(event.keyCode == 123) {
    return false;
}
if(e.ctrlKey && e.shiftKey && e.keyCode == 'I'.charCodeAt(0)){
    return false;
}
if(e.ctrlKey && e.shiftKey && e.keyCode == 'J'.charCodeAt(0)){
    return false;
}
if(e.ctrlKey && e.keyCode == 'U'.charCodeAt(0)){
    return false;
}
if(e.ctrlKey && e.keyCode == 'C'.charCodeAt(0)){
    return false;
}
if(e.ctrlKey && e.keyCode == 'X'.charCodeAt(0)){
    return false;
}
if(e.ctrlKey && e.keyCode == 'Y'.charCodeAt(0)){
    return false;
}
if(e.ctrlKey && e.keyCode == 'Z'.charCodeAt(0)){
    return false;
}
if(e.ctrlKey && e.keyCode == 'V'.charCodeAt(0)){
    return false;
}
if (e.keyCode == 67 && e.shiftKey && (e.ctrlKey || e.metaKey)){
    return false;
}
if (e.keyCode == 'J'.charCodeAt(0) && e.altKey && (e.ctrlKey || e.metaKey)){
    return false;
}
if (e.keyCode == 'I'.charCodeAt(0) && e.altKey && (e.ctrlKey || e.metaKey)){
    return false;
}
if ((e.keyCode == 'V'.charCodeAt(0) && e.metaKey) || (e.metaKey && e.altKey)){
    return false;
}
if (e.ctrlKey && e.shiftKey && e.keyCode == 'C'.charCodeAt(0)){
    return false;
}
if(e.ctrlKey && e.keyCode == 'S'.charCodeAt(0)){
    return false;
}
if(e.ctrlKey && e.keyCode == 'H'.charCodeAt(0)){
    return false;
}
if(e.ctrlKey && e.keyCode == 'A'.charCodeAt(0)){
    return false;
}
if(e.ctrlKey && e.keyCode == 'F'.charCodeAt(0)){
    return false;
}
if(e.ctrlKey && e.keyCode == 'E'.charCodeAt(0)){
    return false;
}
}
if (document.addEventListener) {
    document.addEventListener('contextmenu', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    }, false);
}else{
    document.attachEvent('oncontextmenu', function() {
    window.event.returnValue = false;
    });
}
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

in nextJs you can put this code in the `_app.tsx` or `_app.js` file and use e.key instead of e.keyCode as it is deprecated

```
    useEffect(() => {
    typeof window !== undefined &&
      window.document.addEventListener("contextmenu", (e) => {
        e.preventDefault();
      });
  }, []);

  document.onkeydown = function(e) {
    console.log(e.key)
    if(e.key === 'F12') {
       return false;
    }
    if(e.ctrlKey && e.shiftKey && e.key === 'I') {
       return false;
    }
    if(e.ctrlKey && e.shiftKey && e.key === 'C') {
       return false;
    }
    if(e.ctrlKey && e.shiftKey && e.key === 'J') {
       return false;
    }
    if(e.ctrlKey && e.key === 'u') {
       return false;
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to disable the

- <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>U</kbd>
- <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>I</kbd>
- <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>J</kbd>
- <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd>
- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>U</kbd>
- ...

then you have to add this javascript code to your file.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    document.onkeydown = function(e) {
        if(event.keyCode == 123) {
            return false;
        }
        if(e.ctrlKey && e.shiftKey && e.keyCode == 'I'.charCodeAt(0)){
            return false;
        }
        if(e.ctrlKey && e.shiftKey && e.keyCode == 'J'.charCodeAt(0)){
            return false;
        }
        if(e.ctrlKey && e.shiftKey && e.keyCode == 'C'.charCodeAt(0)){
            return false;
        }
        if(e.ctrlKey && e.keyCode == 'U'.charCodeAt(0)){
            return false;
        }
    }
</script>
```

And, after just add this line in the  tag, see below:

```
<html oncontextmenu="return false;">
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

prevent inspect from the keyboard key and the right click

```
document.addEventListener('contextmenu', (e) => e.preventDefault());
```

function ctrlShiftKey(e, keyCode) {

return e.ctrlKey && e.shiftKey && e.keyCode === keyCode.charCodeAt(0);
}

// Disable F12, Ctrl + Shift + I, Ctrl + Shift + J, Ctrl + U

document.onkeydown = (e) => {

if (event.keyCode === 123 ||

```
ctrlShiftKey(e, 'I') ||
ctrlShiftKey(e, 'J') ||
ctrlShiftKey(e, 'C') ||
(e.ctrlKey && e.keyCode === 'U'.charCodeAt(0)))
return false };
```

Comment: Hey, thanks for pitching in on StackOverflow! Your answer seems a bit unclear and might leave readers scratching their heads. Could you provide more context or clarify your points to make it easier to follow? Feel free to [edit] your answer for better clarity and understanding.

Answer (score -3):

It's easy, just press <kbd>F6</kbd> and then press <kbd>F12</kbd>.