# Disable inspect element in angular 2

Tags: html, angular, typescript

I want to disable inspect element in my website.
currently what happen[image]
i disable the selection of text but user can still copy through the inspect element.

Comment: You can't avoid browser inspect element, this is a browser feature, not something related to your page.

Comment: Why do you want to do that? Also, how do you think you could possibly do that?

Comment: Why/ What do you want to achieve?

Comment: You still can inspect another element and then navigate to the element you actually want. If you still want to disable inspecting a specific element you can add a custom context menu or call `preventDefault` on right-click events. If the user disables JavaScript he still can inspect the element.

Comment: See this below link, and Try it. [click here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28690564/is-it-possible-to-remove-inspect-element)

Comment: See this link below, and try it. [click me](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28690564/is-it-possible-to-remove-inspect-element)

Answer (score 1):

You can place this code in your `app.component.ts` (or any component you need to) in order to prevent users to access mouse right click

```
document.addEventListener('contextmenu', function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
});
```

Also you can have this code to prevent users open inspector by keyboard shortcuts:

```
@HostListener('document:keydown', ['$event'])
handleKeyboardEvent(e: KeyboardEvent) {
    if (e.key === 'F12') {
        return false;
    }
    if (e.ctrlKey && e.shiftKey && e.key === "I") {
        return false;
    }
    if (e.ctrlKey && e.shiftKey && e.key === "C") {
        return false;
    }
    if (e.ctrlKey && e.shiftKey && e.key === "J") {
        return false;
    }
    if (e.ctrlKey && e.key == "U") {
        return false;
    }
    return true;
}
```

Here is full example:

```
import { Component, HostListener, OnInit } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})
export class AppComponent implements OnInit {
  @HostListener('document:keydown', ['$event'])
  handleKeyboardEvent(e: KeyboardEvent) {
    console.log(e)
    if (e.key === 'F12') {
      return false;
    }
    if (e.ctrlKey && e.shiftKey && e.key === "I") {
      return false;
    }
    if (e.ctrlKey && e.shiftKey && e.key === "C") {
      return false;
    }
    if (e.ctrlKey && e.shiftKey && e.key === "J") {
      return false;
    }
    if (e.ctrlKey && e.key == "U") {
      return false;
    }
    return true;
  }

  constructor() {
    document.addEventListener('contextmenu', function(e) {
      e.preventDefault();
    });
  }
  
  // rest of it...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Normally user can be able to inspect code by pressing F12 or right click. 
If we are able to disable this both things you can achieve your goal.

[Further detail see here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24319786/how-to-hide-form-code-from-view-code-inspect-element-browser)

Answer (score -1):

The problem is that in order for a page to work the browser needs to recieve the html document (and all related files). Even if all browsers would provide an API for disabling the option of seeing the plain text document in the browser, I could still write my own application that sends http requests and recieves plain text responses. So if you wish to fo this to "increase security" or "protect your intelectual work", I'm sorry to let you know that this is imposible (and also a bad idea, even if it where posible)

Comment: I mean that it in inspect element whole iframe is open but i don't want to show iframe content in inspect elements.