# Block Inspect element on particular html page

Tags: jquery, html

I want Block Inspect on the particular HTML page.
With support only google chrome.
Please provide some code.

Comment: It's not possible to do this. Sure there are some short-sighted solutions, as in the answers below, but there is *always* a way around it. Your effort would be much better spent on sanitising the data you receive in each request on the server to ensure it's valid.

Answer (score 0):

Try this code --

```
$(document).keydown(function (event) {
  if (event.keyCode == 123) {
    return false;
  } else if ((event.ctrlKey && event.shiftKey && event.keyCode == 73) || (event.ctrlKey && event.shiftKey && event.keyCode == 74) || (event.ctrlKey && event.keyCode == 75) ||  (event.ctrlKey && event.keyCode == 67) || (event.ctrlKey && event.keyCode == 9)) {
    return false;
  }
});
```

Comment: You could do this, then I'll just right click -> Inspect element. If you disable that then I'll temporarily disable JS, then open dev tools. In other words, there is no single worthwhile way of stopping people accessing dev tools, and neither should you waste your time trying.

Comment: @SAVe: Thanks to its work. But inspect element also open Another browser.

Answer (score 0):

You should block the user to perform below actions,

Right Click

F12

Ctrl + Shift + I

Ctrl + Shift + J

Ctrl + Shift + C

Ctrl + U

More at [Is it possible to remove "Inspect Element"?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28690564/is-it-possible-to-remove-inspect-element)

```
document.onkeydown = function(e) {
  if(event.keyCode == 123) {
     return false;
  }
  if(e.ctrlKey && e.shiftKey && e.keyCode == 'I'.charCodeAt(0)) {
     return false;
  }
  if(e.ctrlKey && e.shiftKey && e.keyCode == 'C'.charCodeAt(0)) {
     return false;
  }
  if(e.ctrlKey && e.shiftKey && e.keyCode == 'J'.charCodeAt(0)) {
     return false;
  }
  if(e.ctrlKey && e.keyCode == 'U'.charCodeAt(0)) {
     return false;
  }
}
```

Comment: You could do this, then I'll just right click -> Inspect element. If you disable that then I'll temporarily disable JS, then open dev tools. In other words, there is no single worthwhile way of stopping people accessing dev tools, and neither should you waste your time trying.

Comment: Also, if you believe the question is a duplicate, then please vote to close it as such. Copying an answer from elsewhere is effectively  plagiarism.

Comment: Apologies, I thought it was 2.5k that got you that privilege.