# Passing Sensitive Data

Tags: django, ajax

`Teachers` have access to a list of their `Student`s classes. On this page (one page per `Student`) the `Teachers` can mark a checkbox as `completed` if the Student completes that class. This is done with ajax. I'm passing the current `Students` `id` by making it a value on the checkbox. This is not good as a malicious `Teacher` could inspect the page and change the `Students` `id` in the checkbox element (so they could be on `Student` 111's page and change the field in the checkbox to 112 and mark that other `Student`s class as complete.

How can I prevent them from doing this? I know I can get current users data in POST or using a token, but the `Student` whose checkbox is being changed isn't the current user, current user is a `Teacher` and he is making changes to one of his `Students`. The url is something like this: `/website/teacher/student111/classes/`.

```
def post_form_api(request):
    data = {}

    if request.method == "POST":
        class_id = request.POST.get("class_id")
        student_id = request.POST.get("student_id")

        student_class_data_entry = get_object_or_404(StudentClassData, student_id=student_id, class_id=class_id)

        form = StudentClassDataForm(request.POST, instance=student_class_data_entry)
        
        [.. other logic .]

        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()
            data = {'result' : True}

        if request.is_ajax():
            return JsonResponse(data)
        else:
            return HttpResponseBadRequest()
```

(`value` says which of the Students classes has been changed)

```
<form>
    {% csrf_token %}
    <td class='class_complete' student_id='{{ student.student.id }}' name='completed' value='{{ class.id }}'>{{ item.completed }}</td>
</form>
```

```
$(".class_complete").click(function(e){
    var csrfToken = $("input[name='csrfmiddlewaretoken']");
    class_id = $(this).attr('value');
    student_id = $(this).attr('student_id');

    var checked = $('#'+e.target.id).is(":checked");

    $.ajax({ url: "/api/post_form/",
        type: "POST",
        dataType: "json",
        data: {'completed':checked, 'student_id':student_id, 'class_id':class_id, 'csrfmiddlewaretoken':csrfToken.val()},
        cache: false
    }).done(function(data) {
        if (data.result === true){
        }
        else {
        }
    });
});
```

Thank you.

Comment: If you actually meant the inspect (ctrl-shift-i) function, [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28690644) may help you.

Comment: I appreciate your help, though I will try to find another way to pass the data rather than preventing the user from inspecting the page. Thanks again

Answer (score 0):

Lots of ways to do this.  One would be to make the form field a hash of a 'secret_key', 'student_name', and 'student_id'.  Then it would appear as something opaque, like:

```
<td class='class_complete' user_hash='wkfjr8fjsf8je8jfkokjl' name='completed' value='1235'>completed</td>
```

On the backend, you could decrypt the hash and make sure the `student_id` matched that for the 'student_name'

Comment: Thank you. This sounds like what I'm after. I've had a Google and there doesn't seem to be a clear-cut way to do this with Django. It's going to take some research. Before I begin do you mind telling me if I should look into hashing the ```student_id``` in the database, or hashing it in my views.py and comparing it to my unhashed DB ```student_id```. Thank you.

Comment: You can just hash it in the view.  It's not so sensitive (like a password) where it should be encrypted in the db.