# How can I prevent Inspect Element with Javascript?

Tags: javascript

I'm making a game and I want to prevent anyone doing Inspect Element(right click, developer tools, etc) using Javascript.

I tried

```
oncontextmenu='return false'
```

but ctrl + shift + I or ctrl + shift + J or ctrl + shift + C or developer tools still allows inspect.

Comment: not gonna happen, nope nope nope. You can not disable it.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28690564/is-it-possible-to-remove-inspect-element

Comment: maybe helpful https://github.com/sindresorhus/devtools-detect

Comment: There are obnoxious solutions that try to do something akin to `eval("debugger;")` and then try to measure the time it takes to run this, asynchronously. If the dev tools are not open, this statement does nothing, so it takes little more than 0 ms; otherwise, it takes more time. Those solutions then clear the console and refresh the site, making usage of dev tools impossible. But scripts that do this can still be blocked using ad blockers or userscript managers.

Answer (score -3):

**You can't**, but this will block right click:

```
document.addEventListener("contextmenu", (e) => {
  e.preventDefault();
});
```